# Nested iif() Statement is "Too Complex" to run within MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am currently updating a database that I created for work to classify transactions into a transaction type. This requires me to use an iif() statement that has become too complex to run. Before we get too far along, I want to apologize for the lengthy description, but I want to make sure I provide enough information.

## **To set the stage**

Transactions (RefID's) can be one of the following:

- 3PL
- 4PL
- Air Freight
- Customs Only

One of the complexities of this task involves the fact that a Charge Code ("CC"), similar to an item number or service name, can be 3PL or 4PL depending on the circumstances of the transaction. For example, if the CC of Ocean_Freight exists on a RefID that also has a CC of PO_Management, the transaction is a 3PL transaction. However, if the CC of PO_Management exists without Ocean_Freight on the RefID, this would be a 4PL Transaction.

I have the following CC's which can be used to define a transaction:

## CC Descriptions

**3PL Only**

- Ocean_Freight

  - this CC will define the transaction unless there is a CC from the "3PL or 4PL Depending on Situation" section below
- Drayage Management

  - this CC will define the transaction unless there is a CC from the "3PL or 4PL Depending on Situation" section below

**Air Freight Only**

- Air_Freight

**3PL or 4PL Depending on Situation**

- PO_Management

  - 3PL when CC exists on a RefID with Ocean_Freight or Drayage Management
  - 4PL when CC exists on a RefID without the aforementioned CC's
- CROM Fee

  - 3PL when CC exists on a RefID with Ocean_Freight or Drayage Management
  - 4PL when CC exists on a RefID without Ocean_Freight, Drayage Management, or PO_Management
- EDI

  - 3PL when CC exists on a RefID with Ocean_Freight or Drayage Management
  - 4PL when CC exists on a RefID without Ocean_Freight, Drayage Management, or PO_Management
- Booking Management Fee

  - 3PL when CC exists on a RefID with Ocean_Freight or Drayage Management
  - 4PL when CC exists on a RefID without Ocean_Freight, Drayage Management, PO_Management, or EDI
- Forwarding Fee

  - 3PL when CC exists on a RefID with Ocean_Freight or Drayage Management
  - 4PL when CC exists on a RefID without Ocean_Freight, Drayage Management, PO_Management, EDI, or Booking Management Fee
- Handling Charge

  - 3PL when CC exists on a RefID with Ocean_Freight or Drayage Management
  - 4PL when CC exists on a RefID without Ocean_Freight, Drayage Management, PO_Management, EDI, Booking Management Fee, or Forwarding Fee

**Customs Only**

**As a note** - each of the preceding CC's can be considered what I classify as a Transaction Defining Charge Code (TDCC), in the absence of one of these CC's and the presence of the Customs Entry CC, the transaction is defined as a "Customs Only" transaction.

A Sample Transaction:

[image]

## **What I have done to this point**

I previously accomplished this within Access using a nested iif() statement, but in some cases I was pulling duplicate records because I wasn't isolating each of the CC's. For example, if PO_Management and Handling Charge existed on the same transaction, both would get ascribed a value of "4PL", when in reality, I only want one to define the transaction. This is what sent me down this path of repairing the code.

The query that drives most of this is called "Step 2)" and it does a sum(iif(criteria here),1,0) based on whether or not a CC exists on a RefID. It provides a value of >0 if a CC exists on a RefID which allows me to reference this query to determine how I should define a RefID.

To further refine my original methodology, I made another query called "Steps." Within this query is where I apply the logic from above within the CC descriptions section above.

I have tried using a nested iif() statement and also tried using the Switch() function, but both get to the same point, "The expression you entered is too complex." I have done some research and I believe the answer is a Private Function using VBA, but I have had no luck understanding how to create the functions. Does anyone have a better way of attacking this problem? Please find a sample of my latest attempt at a switch() function which kicks out the error below:

```
Transaction Type: 

    Switch(
      [Steps]![OF] > 0           And [Steps]![CC] = "Ocean Freight","3PL",
      [Steps]![AF] > 0           And [Steps]![CC] = "Air_Freight","Air Freight",
      [Steps]![Dray] > 0         And [Steps]![CC] = "Drayage Management","3PL",
      [Steps]![PO 4PL] > 0       And [Steps]![CC] = "PO_Management","4PL",
      [Steps]![PO 3PL] > 0       And [Steps]![CC] = "PO_Management","3PL",
      [Steps]![CROM 4PL] > 0     And [Steps]![CC] = "CROM Fee","4PL",
      [Steps]![CROM 3PL] > 0     And [Steps]![CC] = "CROM Fee","3PL",
      [Steps]![EDI 4PL] > 0      And [Steps]![CC] = "EDI","4PL",
      [Steps]![EDI 3PL] > 0      And [Steps]![CC] = "EDI","3PL",
      [Steps]![BMF 4PL] > 0      And [Steps]![CC] = "Booking Management Fee","4PL",
      [Steps]![BMF 3PL] > 0      And [Steps]![CC] = "Booking Management Fee","3PL",
      [Steps]![FF 4PL] > 0       And [Steps]![CC] = "Forwarding Fee","4PL",
      [Steps]![FF 3PL] > 0       And [Steps]![CC] = "Forwarding Fee","3PL", 
      [Steps]![Handling 4PL] > 0 And [Steps]![CC] = "Handling Charge","4PL", 
      [Steps]![Handling 3PL] > 0 And [Steps]![CC] = "Handling Charge","3PL"
    )
```

## What Needs to Happen?

Ultimately, I want to reference the "Steps" Query to drive a Field in my output query called "transaction type." This is, of course, where things go sideways for me because I cannot get enough nests within my iif() statement. This suggests to me that I am going about this all wrong and a far simpler solution exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a relatively straightforward 1-to-1 mapping situation. An efficient and flexible way to tackle this would be to create a mapping table that encapsulates your rules:

```
OF  AF  Dray  [PO 4PL]  [PO 3PL]  [CROM 4PL]  CC                     RefId
1                                             "Ocean Freight"        "3PL"
    1                                         "Air_Freight"          "Air Freight"
        1                                     "Drayage Management"   "3PL"
              1                               "PO_Management"        "4PL"
                        1                     "PO_Management"        "3PL"
                                  1           "CROM Fee"             "4PL"
```

Add more columns to the table for the other fields you want to check.

Now a SELECT (or similar UPDATE statement) can be written that picks the RefId based on the rules in the table (warning, this is pseudocode, I don't have MS Access to test this right now):

```
SELECT
  t.*
  r.RefId
FROM
  Transactions t
  LEFT JOIN TransactionMappings m ON
    t.CC = m.CC
    AND (
      (t.OF > 0 AND m.OF = 1) OR
      (t.AF > 0 AND m.AF = 1) OR
      (t.Dray > 0 AND m.Dray = 1) OR
      (t.[PO 4PL] > 0 AND m.[PO 4PL] = 1) OR
      (t.[PO 3PL] > 0 AND m.[PO 3PL] = 1)
    )
```

Advantages would be

- comparatively clean code
- you can modify mapping rules without having to rewrite the SQL
- a JOIN is (likely) to be faster than a nested/complex `Switch()` although this would need to be measured
- making this more complex is comparatively easy (things like "add a numeric range to check against", or "make an exception in certain cases" come down to adding more columns to the mapping table and specifying more JOIN conditions), making the nested `Switch()` more complex in the same way is comparatively hard.

Comment: Hey Tomalak, I think I am super close, but I am messing something up with the syntax. I know you said that you don't have access to check syntax, but does this look off to you? 

`SELECT Steps.refid, Steps.CC
 
 FROM Steps INNER JOIN TransactionMappings ON Steps.CC = TransactionMappings.CC

 WHERE (([Steps]![PO 4PL]>"0" And [TransactionMappings]![PO 4PL]="1"))

GROUP BY Steps.refid, Steps.CC;`

Sorry for the formatting, I am not sure how to format it within the comment field.

Comment: I don't know - what happens? Is there an error message?

Comment: Oh,  I get a "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" error -- I have tried doing this in the Design View of MS-Access in the "Criteria" section and set to a "Where"  -- here is a snapshot: https://imgur.com/a/m3n7E7S

Comment: As a general tip, don't use the Query Builder. Write actual SQL. It says "data type mismatch" so I guess you are trying to use datatypes that don't correspond to each other. Check that the `CC` field in both tables has the same datatype, and that the other fields either really *are* Text - or that you don't use `"1"` when you mean `1`.

Comment: Okay! I think I have it now, Tomalak! Thank you so much for your patience, below is the code that is compiling!

`SELECT Steps.refid, Steps.CC, TransactionMappings.[Transaction Type]
FROM Steps INNER JOIN TransactionMappings ON Steps.CC = TransactionMappings.CC
WHERE ((([Steps]![PO 4PL])>0) AND (([TransactionMappings]![PO 4PL])=1) or ([Steps]![PO 3PL])>0) AND (([TransactionMappings]![PO 3PL]))
GROUP BY Steps.refid, Steps.CC, TransactionMappings.[Transaction Type];`

Answer (score 3):

The *Too complex* error occurs when you have too many arguments for a function. An easy fix is to split up the switch:

You can easily split up `Switch(Compare1, Result1, Compare2, Result2, Compare3, Result3, Compare4, Result4)` to `Switch(Compare1, Result1, Compare2, Result2, True, Switch(Compare3, Result3, Compare4, Result4))`. While we've really increased complexity, our individual switch statements take less arguments, thus Access will be less likely to complain.

For your example, splitting it in two would look like:

```
Switch([Steps]![OF]>0 And [Steps]![CC]="Ocean Freight","3PL",
    [Steps]![AF]>0 And [Steps]![CC]="Air_Freight","Air Freight",
        [Steps]![Dray]>0 And [Steps]![CC]="Drayage Management","3PL",
            [Steps]![PO 4PL]>0 And [Steps]![CC]="PO_Management","4PL",
                [Steps]![PO 3PL]>0 And [Steps]![CC]="PO_Management","3PL",
                    [Steps]![CROM 4PL]>0 And [Steps]![CC]="CROM Fee","4PL",
                        [Steps]![CROM 3PL]>0 And [Steps]![CC]="CROM Fee","3PL",
                            [Steps]![EDI 4PL]>0 And [Steps]![CC]="EDI","4PL",
                                True, Switch(
                                     [Steps]![EDI 3PL]>0 And [Steps]![CC]="EDI","3PL",
                                        [Steps]![BMF 4PL]>0 And [Steps]![CC]="Booking Management Fee","4PL",
                                            [Steps]![BMF 3PL]>0 And [Steps]![CC]="Booking Management Fee","3PL",
                                                [Steps]![FF 4PL]>0 And [Steps]![CC]="Forwarding Fee","4PL",
                                                    [Steps]![FF 3PL]>0 And [Steps]![CC]="Forwarding Fee","3PL", 
                                                        [Steps]![Handling 4PL] >0 and [Steps]![CC]="Handling Charge","4PL", 
                                                            [Steps]![Handling 3PL] >0 and [Steps]![CC]="Handling Charge","3PL"))
```

That's still a fair amount of arguments, so you might need to split it in 3 parts.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly creating a private function is quite simple the code goes like this:

```
Private Function functionName(Arguments)

'your code here

End function
```

The only problem would be that even with a function your switch statement itself is far too long and complex. You are getting duplicate values because it will have multiple "true" values. To solve this a set of If and Else If statements would work better. Check this page out for more details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-ifthenelse-statements

Comment: That's an easy solution, but in situations where user has large tables and/or has its tables on SQL Sever or Oracle, the performance will be much worse than with Iif() or Switch() based statements.